# Flutter: Cant position a container over another using offset

Tags: animation, flutter, stack, containers

So I have written this code which lets an animation play where i pressed. So if i press the screen there is a short animation playing where i pressed, if you press multiple times there are multiple animations on the screen for a short period. Each time I press the screen there is a container taking up place where the animation is played, but I cant stack a container over another, So if i press on the screen where there already is a container an animation won't be played. It seems that Positioned wont work if i press where there already is a container. How do I stack a container over another so that I can press on the same place and play multiple animation over another?

This is all the code responsible for that animation:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
@override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> 


 with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final tappedPositions = <Offset>[];

  AnimationController _animationController;


  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    );

    super.initState();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
         new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
           new Expanded(
              child: Container( 
                color: Colors.blue,
              ))]),  

         new GestureDetector(
            onTapDown: (tabDetails) {
              setState(() {
                tappedPositions.add(tabDetails.localPosition);
                Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                  tappedPositions.removeLast();
                });


              });
            },
            child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[

        Container(
              height: 370,
              color: Colors.transparent
            ),
        ])
         ),
          for (final position in tappedPositions)
            Positioned(

              top: position.dy-50,
              left: position.dx-50,
              child: MyAnimatedWidget(
                animation: _animationController,
              ))]);




  }
}
  class MyAnimatedWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Animation animation;

  const MyAnimatedWidget({Key key, this.animation}) : super(key: key);

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animation,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[

        Container(

        height: 100.0,
        width: 100.0,

       color: Colors.red


/* new FlareActor(
         "assets/images/tryck2.flr",
         animation:"tryck",*/


        ),
        ],
      ),

      builder: (context, child) {
        return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(alignment: Alignment.center,

          child: child,)
          ],


        );
      },
    );
  }



  }
```

PS (I have already asked this question and tried to make it work but have not succeeded, therefore I am asking again, I'm new to dart and programing in general)

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile, maybe you missed something when copying it?

Comment: @monkey Thank you for the feedback! I've edited it so that it should work and commented out the animation part, it will now show a red container instead of my animation as that animation is made using flare and needs therefore to be downloaded as an asset.